# unexpected css token: bootstrap, gradient, carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a random quote app using javascript, jQuery, bootstrap on codepen.  It was fine there.  Then I organized files, pushed to git and tried to view from safari.  I got these warnings and the page is not looking right.  Did I miss something while transferring?  Thanks for any help.

```
  [Warning] Unexpected CSS token: : (bootstrap.min.css, line 5)
  [Warning] Unexpected CSS token: : (bootstrap.min.css, line 5)
  [Warning] Unexpected CSS token: : (bootstrap.min.css, line 5)
```

Comment: You appear to have an additional, or misplaced, ":" on line 5 in bootstrap.min.css. I would assume that "Organizing files" somehow messed something up. Or something else did.

Comment: @xiix  Thank you for your help.  But I don't maintain bootstrap.min.css file.  It is very odd.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could try replacing it with the unminified version, bootstrap.css, run again, check where you get the error, and try to trace it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `bootstrap.css`, not `bootstrap.min.css`.

Search for `progid`, you will find 3 lines, just comment them out, like this:

```
/*filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);*/
```

Then you will never meet the errors. Basically I believe these lines are for Internet Explorer 8, as it is out of market, I don't care it anymore.